# UIAlertView delegate not getting called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uialertview

I have a parent class and 5 sub classes. Out of these 5 there are 2 classes(sub) where I have used AlertView and have used alert delegate method.
In sub classes I have one common button through which parent class' alert delegate is getting called. It's "Logout" button. Through which parent class' alert delegate is accessible. So what happens is the classes where I have used alert delegate (in my case there are 2 such classes) the parent class' delegate is not getting called . But the class where I haven't use alert view from those classes parent class' delegate is getting called.
I don't know whether I am making sense or not, if not then let me know I will try again to explain better.

```
//parent class
-(void)someMethod
{
    UIAlertView * alertView =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:ALERT_TITLE message:@"Are you sure want to logout?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];

    [alertView show];
}

// not getting called "only" when I have alert view in my sub class
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [[AppDelegate appDelegate]logout];
        [[AppDelegate appDelegate]saveWelComeBool:YES];
    }
}


 //sub class
 ParentClass *parent = [[ParentClass alloc]init];
 [parent someMethod];// method is getting called but not the alert delegate

-(void)someMethod2
{
    UIAlertView * alertView =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:ALERT_TITLE message:@"Are you sure want to logout?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];

    [alertView show];
}

//getting called
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [[AppDelegate appDelegate]logout];
        [[AppDelegate appDelegate]saveWelComeBool:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be that the `parent` be released

Comment: Add - (void)dealloc { NSLog(@"%@", self);} to ParentClass, you will find it be dealloced

Comment: Is this for iOS 8? If so you should be using UIAlertController anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method from the subclass.

If your 2nd class is subclassing the 1st class (Parent class), you don't need to re-implement the parent class methods in the subclass, unless you are adding some extra functionality. As the 2nd class has already inherited all the parent class methods.

So, if you remove the delegate method from the subclass, the parent class method will automatically be called.

Comment: Can you update your question to show the final code of the parent and sub class. Also I don't understand why did you create parent's class object in the subclass. Seeing the whole code would make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the parent class with `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` instead of the sub-class, then the alertView delegate will be called in parent and all of its subclasses. Just make sure, you don't reconfirm the subclass again with `<UIAlertViewDelegate>`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had face same issue if you define **alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:** delegate method both class i.e. super class and sub class then super class method will not called for that you have to remove delegate method from sub class.